# Coloring graph with only one cycle

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Find chromatic number of connected graph that contains only one cycle.
I'm not sure how to even start this, probably we have two cases, first if it is cycle of even length, and second cycle with odd lenght. Then I know that chromatic number of odd cycle is $3$, and of even cycle is $2$. But how to use that here? Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Note that connected graph with only one cycle is just tree + 1 extra edge (remove the edge from cycle and you will be left with tree).

Chromatic number of tree is 2. Also, in tree, 2 vertices colored same if path length is even. So when you add new edge, if you add it to vertices with same color, then chromatic number will be 3 (odd cycle case), otherwise, it is still 2 (even cycle).

Answer (score 1):

Just look at a cycle graph, $C_n$ and start coloring.  The answer pops out:

[image]